# How can I hide status bar in Kitkat and above version device completely even if the finger is swiped from top of screen?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to hide status bar in my Android application.

I used following:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

It works fine below Kitkat. But after upgrading to Kitkat when we swipe finger from top of screen, the status bar appears again as it works as immersive mode.

I don't want this behavior. And the status bar should not appear if finger is swiped from top of screen. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to permanently hide it?

Comment: Yes i am trying to completely hide it in my application

Comment: See my answer, you cannot permanently hide it but I have posted a workaround

Answer (score 0):

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

add this in your manifest of the activity.

Comment: The problem is for Android Kitkat and above version. This thing is not working. if i swipe the finger from top of screen, Status bar comes automatically and after some time automatically goes of the screen.I dont want to come status bar if finger is swipped from top of screen

Answer (score 0):

You cannot permanently hide it. Perhaps consider an overlay that consumes touch events. I have used this:

`onCreate()`

```
    WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags =
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
    localLayoutParams.flags = 0x80000000 | localLayoutParams.flags;
    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (25 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View overlay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.systembar_overlay, null);
    manager.addView(overlay, localLayoutParams);
```

`systembar_overlay.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:longClickable="false">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This shows a black bar in place of the original. You could make it transparent, or add more widgets to it. You may have to tweak the height to suit your needs.

Comment: I am not able to vote u as i have not sufficient points to vote any one(less than 15). Your answer was helpful for me and its correct